# запрет писать в JSpinner swing

Tags: java, swing

Как сделать так, чтобы в `JSpinner` вручную нельзя было вводить текст.

Пробовал

```
spinner.setFocusable(false);
```

Но это не работает

Comment: `setFocusable(false)` - это вы так снимаете фокус с компонента, а не запрещаете им пользоваться.

Comment: Получилось что-нибудь?

Answer (score 1):

Компонент `JSpinner` в составе имеет редактор, который в свою очередь в своем составе имеет обычное текстовое поле.

**Вам необходимо:**

1. Получить редактор (с помощью метода `getEditor()`)
2. Чтобы иметь дело не с `JComponent`, а конкретной реализацией редактора, вам необходимо привести полученное значение к типу редактора по умолчанию(`JSpinner.DefaultEditor`)
3. Из редактора Вы уже можете получить свое текстовое поле (`getTextField()`)
4. И уже на нем запретить редактирование(`setEditable(false)`)

**Подробно и по шагам:**

```java
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
// получаем редактор
JComponent editorComponent = spinner.getEditor();
// приводим значение JComponent к типу редактора спинера по умолчанию(JSpinner.DefaultEditor)
JSpinner.DefaultEditor editor = (JSpinner.DefaultEditor)editorComponent;
// из редактора получаем текстовое поле (JFormattedTextField)
JFormattedTextField textField = editor.getTextField();
// отключаем редактирование на данном поле
textField.setEditable(false);
```

**Все тоже самое только в одну строку:**

```java
((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) spinner.getEditor()).getTextField().setEditable(false);
```

За основу был взят ответ:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29105457/4558866